# Adding author and date to git describe

Tags: git

I have started a changelog using git describe and it works great except for the fact that I would like to show who the author was of the commit and the date that it was committed. Is this possible to do?

Thank you

**Update:** Here is the alias I use in my config file to spit out my changelog:

```
changelog = "!f() { r=${1:-`git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..HEAD}; 
echo Changelog for $r; gi    t log --reverse --no-merges --format='* %s' $r; }; f"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I think you can.

You could pipe the output of describe to show and subsequently apply a formatting string to display the author and date of the relevant commit. For example:

```
git describe HEAD | xargs git show -s --format=format:"Author: %an%nDate: %cd"
```

Try giving that a go, though I cannot say it is full proof! :-)

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it did not work with what I am using right now. Sorry I did not add this to my initial question. I have updated my question.

Comment: Apologies, but I am not too flash on my shell scripting so I cannot quite grasp what exactly you are chasing. How about modifying the format string you already have to include author and date details, would they be the ones you are after?